# How do I create an empty Stream in Java?

Tags: java, java-stream, enumerable

In C# I would use [`Enumerable.Empty()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341042(v=vs.110).aspx), but how do I create an empty `Stream` in Java?

Comment: StackOverflow is more google-able than the documentation.

Comment: You don’t need google at all. There is exactly one address to bookmark once when starting to develop Java software, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api which is the official API documentation containing each package, class and member in a structure not requiring a search engine to find them.

Comment: When you already know that it exists, then yes. But Java abounds with library methods that you might hope exist, but turn out not to (or not where you thought, or with the name you thought), and you could spend quite a bit of your life looking for them if you always made the API doc your first port of call.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

As simple as this: [`Stream.empty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#empty--)

Comment: For a specific type stream, use `Stream.<T>empty()`, i.e `Stream.<String>empty()`

Comment: @Mugen no, you should not. Why do you think that?

Comment: Because if you don't, compiler assumes the type is `Stream<? extends Object>`, and why won't it?

Comment: @Mugen you need to provide an example or ask a question, this is not how type inference should work.

Comment: I provided a tip, if you think I'm wrong I'll delete it as this is your answer and I don't intend to start a new discussion.

Comment: I would use Stream.builder()

Answer (score 13):

```
Stream<String> emptyStr = Stream.of();
```

`emptyStr.count()` returns 0 (zero).

In addition:

- For a primitive stream like `IntStream`, `IntStream.of()` works in
  similar way (also the `empty` method). `IntStream.of(new int[]{})` also returns an empty stream.
- The `Arrays` class has stream creation methods which accept an
  array of primitives or an object type. This can be used to create
  an empty stream; e.g.,: `System.out.println(Arrays.stream(new int[]{}).count());` prints    zero.
- Any stream created from a collection (like a `List` or `Set`)    with
  zero elements can return an empty stream; for example: `new ArrayList<Integer>().stream()` returns an empty stream of type `Integer`.

Comment: This is shorter than the accepted answer; it makes you wonder why `Stream.empty()` was created.

Comment: In oppposite to `Stream.empty()`, it creates empty array internally, performs null check on it etc. You can look it up in implementation.